# Getting SSL Handshake error handshake Failure

Tags: docker, ssl, salesforce, websphere-liberty

[image]We have a docker image of Open Liberty and have deployed in Azure, we are getting SSL error wrt to Salesforce (HTTPS) API call and I suspect something is wrong with the way we have this certificate exported and imported in our environment. Any help on the following error (Stack trace):-

```
2019-04-29T13:04:01.194316292Z [err] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2019-04-29T13:04:01.198835521Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:42)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.205285564Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:37)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.208038782Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.b(av.java:549)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.212706712Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:715)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.212718412Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.i(av.java:574)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.217931346Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:280)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.217990947Z [err]    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.startHandshake(av.java:431)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.222258175Z [err]    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.223138981Z [err]    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.223641984Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.232638943Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.232666443Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242805310Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242819510Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242824010Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242865710Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242879410Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242883210Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242887010Z [err]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242890810Z [err]    at com.afpva.botframework.connector.salesforce.SalesforceAgentConnector.checkAgentOnline(SalesforceAgentConnector.java:332)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.242894710Z [err]    at com.afpva.botframework.connector.salesforce.SalesforceAgentConnector.chatMessage(SalesforceAgentConnector.java:66)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.271353797Z [err]    at com.afpva.botframework.connector.vaconnector.VAConnector.sendMessageToSalesforceAgent(VAConnector.java:224)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.271523698Z [err]    at com.afpva.botframework.connector.vaconnector.VAConnector.sendMessageToVAController(VAConnector.java:147)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300596188Z [err]    at com.afpva.botframework.connector.web.NewWebConnector.handleTextMessage(NewWebConnector.java:130)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300611289Z [err]    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300616189Z [err]    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300620089Z [err]    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300624389Z [err]    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58)
2019-04-29T13:04:01.300628289Z [err]    at
```

Comment: Handshake failure is typically a mismatched level of TLS or cipher suites between the server and Java environment. That is, not a missing certificate.

Comment: ty dbreaux, apprecaite your response. Should I modify my server.xml file (since I have docker image created) and support the TLSv1.2 or something? Any advice on tht front? where I can look for which version is supported and which version SSL has?

Comment: What version of Liberty, with what version of Java? And you can test the Salesforce server's supported TLS and ciphers at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. A few links that might help: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_ssl.html 
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/configuring-ssl-liberty/

Comment: We are using Open Liberty:WebProfile 8 from Docker to build our custom image with our app deployed as part of the image. My colleage just informed that the Servers is Salesforce one allows TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 and we use Azure whcih allows TLS1.2. As I am new to this I am not sure if the server.xml is missing something and that is causing this issue. My Server.xml looks like:- <server description="new server">

Comment: <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
         <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
  <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
   </featureManager>
   <classloading useJarUrls="true"/>
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
      <user name="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
      <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadminpwd"/>
   </basicRegistry>

Comment: Even in Azure, running from a Docker image, you'll be using the Java version and settings that are part of the Open Liberty image. It's not just the TLS versions that matter, but also which specific "cipher suites" are enabled for those TLS versions. So you need to see which ciphers the Salesforce server supports, and see if the defaults the Liberty Java supports overlap with that, and if not, change the Liberty server.xml `<ssl>` `enabledCiphers` and/or `sslProtocol` to match.

Comment: ty dbreaux, my colleague enabled further logs and this what the logs are showing..I am still not able to understand from it as in Azure we are simply provisioning that as web-app (this being container host) for the Docker image. this is the error log which some additional info.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZkj.png

Comment: It appears from your log that your Liberty configuration only has TLSv1. So, not 1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: aah yes I see now that in the log, but I do see when communicating to azurewebsites.. it does say enabled TLSV1.2.. as shown in log below:- 
2019-04-29T20:56:57.058857065Z 2019-04-29 20:56:57.057 DEBUG 1 --- [cutor-thread-35] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Connecting socket to abcchatbotcontroller.azurewebsites.net/137.116.78.243:443 with timeout 0
2019-04-29T20:56:57.333395116Z 2019-04-29 20:56:57.332 DEBUG 1 --- [cutor-thread-35] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]...  so I m guessing somewhere in code it needs 2 b fixed to use TLSv1.2?

Comment: something like what Mulesoft had an issue with:-> https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/SSL-handshake-fails-due-to-TLSv1-used-on-IBM-JDK

Comment: RESOLVED it, Dev team fixed the client code to force TLSv1.2 from there end and now the salesforce calls are going thru.